# Prove that Cauchy-Riemann Equations are satisfied.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Prove that $f(x)$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations at the point $z=0$

$$f(z) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\overline{z}^3}{|z|^2},  & \text{if $z$ is not 0} \\
0, & \text{if $z$ = 0}
\end{cases} $$

For $z=x+iy$ i get $u=\frac {x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}, v=\frac {y^3-3yx^2}{x^2+y^2} $ 
Which do not satisfy the C-R Equations. I also tried with polar form which also didn't work. I supect it has to do with the fact that i have to chech the C-R equations on the point $z=0+i0$ but since the function is $0$ at that point, i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$, you have $u(x,0)=x$ and $u(0,y)=0$. Therefore, $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}u(0,0)=1$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. On the other hand, since $v(x,y)=\dfrac{y^3-3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$, you have $v(x,0)=0$ and $v(0,y)=y$. Therefore, $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}u(0,0)=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}(0,0)=1$. So, yes, $(0,0)$ *is* a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: is it possible to show the same thing in polar coordinates?

Comment: Sure. Write$$u(r,\theta)=r(\cos^3(\theta)-3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta))\text{ and }v(r,\theta)=r(\sin^3(\theta)-3\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta))$$and check that$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac1r\times\frac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}\text{ and that}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}=-\frac1r\times\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}.$$