# Why does it suffice to check the cauchy riemann equations in one direction only

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194860/prove-that-cauchy-riemann-equations-are-satisfied) answer. The question is to check that the Cauchy riemann equations for some function hold at $z=0$. The answer sets $y=0$ then takes the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$. I don't understand why he does this instead of $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$, the two are not the same. In fact if you do it my way, the limit does not exist. I have a feeling it is to do with it being a partial derivative in the $x$ direction(so $y$ doesn't matter or something), but I'm not sure.

The example I have is slightly different but:
$$u(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
Set $y=0$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} u(x,0)=1$.

Now consider path along the line $y=x$. $u(x,y)=\frac{4x^2}{2x^2}$ so the limit is 2.

Comment: *In fact if you do it my way, the limit does not exist*  please show this.

Comment: Edited $ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Partial derivatives are 1-variable limits, though.

Comment: You are computing limits of $\frac{u(0,y)-u(0,0)}{y}$ and $\frac{u(x,0)-u(0,0)}{x}$ because the equations are about partial derivatives. We don’t care about $\lim_{x\to 0} u(x,0),$ except that it be equal to $u(0,0),$ which you haven’t defined. The original question is an example to show that some functions can satisfy Cauchy Riemann at a point and still not be “nice.” Not sure about yours, since you don’t tell us what $v$ is, nor what $u(0,0)$ is.